# How to perform verified block by block flash block device copy?

Tags: linux, usb, flash, block-device

I’ve a special flash device where each writes to a physical block must be verified (although I’m not accessing it as a mtd). Because a physical block are always flashed but data writing does not always works.
So this means if I perform a simple unverified copy like this:

```
dd if=backup of=/dev/sdb1
```

I will a have minority of blocks where writing would have been successful, and a majority where only flashing would had been successful (which means some blocks are left filled with`0xFF`).
Simply retrying the command doesn’t works because`dd`would also rewrite successful blocks which means some previous writes would be converted to unsuccessful rewrites (a block with previously valid data would be flashed but got writing failed resulting in `0xFF` filling).

So my block device should be handled with verified copy: after each write access a block should be compared with the `to be copied data` and data writing on such block needs to be reattempted until successful in order to process next block.

Comment: This is similar to `.iso` burning. Except each 512 bytes physical blocks are flashed individually before each writes. The reason for such handling is I don’t need a special driver: so when the kernel requests a write it’s the device firmware who handle flashing the corresponding area on the mtd while also converting serial block access into mtd access (like with an sd card).

Comment: The SLOW way - `man dd`  - count, skip, seek and the related *_bytes arguments.

Comment: @Hannu it’s much more than the slow way : it’s the yearly way ! There’s 500Gb to copy. Imagine time if several process would need to get created every 512bytes.

Comment: Well, I'd guess some quite simple C code might be what is required - as everything is a file. Read up the data in a buffer, seek to the correct position, write, seek back, read and compare. Repeat until you can read back the original data, skip to next buffer-full of data. Note: I have not tried it.